# Old anime about fighting puppets.

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon

Early 2000's probably on cartoon network or adult swim. One of the evil puppets pretty much controlled his human. Main puppet was blond

Comment: [Rozen Maiden](http://www.anime-planet.com/anime/rozen-maiden) ?

Comment: And I should have already pointed out that the more details you can add, the more likely we can answer your question. You can find a list of questions at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info to answer by editing your question.

Comment: You should mark an answer as accepted by clicking on the 'tick' by the answer.

Answer (score 7):

You may be thinking of *[Zatch Bell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zatch_Bell!%5C)* where the "[Mamodo](http://zatchbell.wikia.com/wiki/Mamodo)" are puppet-like demons.

> One hundred Mamodo go to Earth every 1,000 years to battle to be the king of the Mamodo world. Each Mamodo needs a human partner in order to use his or her spell book, a book that seals the powers of the Mamodo. When read aloud, the spells are cast by the Mamodo producing many effects. If the spell book is burned, the Mamodo is forced to return to the Mamodo world, and they lose all claim to the position of the Mamodo king. While the spells in each book typically are different for each Mamodo, there are Mamodo that share spells, like Zatch Bell and his evil twin brother, Zeno Bell. The human and their Mamodo gain these spells through experience and hard work. The last Mamodo standing without their book burnt is the new Mamodo king.

According to Wikipedia, "The English adaptation of the Zatch Bell! anime premiered on Cartoon Network's Toonami on March 5, 2005 to January 20, 2007 with seventy-seven episodes aired."

The main character's Mamodo is [Zatch Bell](http://zatchbell.wikia.com/wiki/Zatch_Bell_and_Kiyo_Takamine) who indeed has blond hair:

[image: Zatch and Kiyo]

[Zofis and Koko](http://zatchbell.wikia.com/wiki/Zofis_and_Koko) are a possible match for the control aspect, but Zofis is not male:

[image: Zofis and Koko]

Answer (score 0):

Or, as noted by student0807055639, this could be *[Rozen Maiden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rozen_Maiden)*.

> In the 20th century, a legendary doll maker named Rozen created seven bisque dolls which were powered and given sentience with a gem called Rosa Mystica. Since then, Rozen sent the dolls away to find masters and to battle among themselves to gather each other's Rosa Mysticas; this competition is referred to as the Alice Game. When a doll obtains all seven, they are to become a perfect doll dubbed as Alice and will be reunited with Rozen. By order of creation, the seven Rozen Maidens are named Suigintou, Kanaria, Suiseiseki, Souseiseki, Shinku, Hinaichigo, and Kirakisho.
>
> *Rozen Maiden* follows Jun Sakurada, a middle school student who has withdrawn from society after suffering persecutions from his classmates. He is chosen to become Shinku's master and joins the Alice Game. As the series progresses, Jun also becomes the master to Hinaichigo and Suiseiseki. After Souseiseki's Rosa Mystica is taken by Suigintou, Jun's Rozen Maidens resolve to revive her and to end the Alice Game peacefully; they later befriend Kanaria who shares their sentiments. However, the group is attacked by Kirakisho who absorbs Hinaichigo and traps Shinku and Suiseiseki in the N-field, a plane of consciousness which connects the universe. *Rozen Maiden* concludes with Jun preparing to enter the N-field to save the dolls.

Shinku is indeed blond. However, while this series was the first one I thought of (before seeing student0807055639 had already commented), I don't believe there to be a male doll.

[image: The dolls]

Also, I can find no indication that Cartoon Network or Adult Swim aired it.

Comment: It was in fact zatch bell. Thank you. Now i can die in peace finally knowing that name

Comment: @Acct: Please accept that answer (which is not this one) by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Angelic Layer from 2001.  Puppet Dolls

Comment: You could improve this answer by [edit]ing it to more clearly explain why you think this might be the correct anime. For example, was there an evil puppet that controlled his human?

Comment: Also, the querent confirmed [via comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/157283/old-anime-about-fighting-puppets#comment412313_157310) that it was *Zatch Bell*